# Dynamic Quiz - support

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, handlebars.js

I saw this [quiz code](http://codepen.io/gcarino/pen/LDgtn/) and I have been trying to modified it in a so that can run as follow

Click to Start Quiz > Question(s) > **Answer to Question(s)** > End of Quiz

So basically the user will start the quiz by clicking on button to start the quiz, once the user answer the question(s), the user will see the correct answer for each question; once all question get answer the user will see his results at the end of the quiz.

```js
/*jshint strict:false */


$(function() {

  'use strict';


  var questions = [{
    question: 'What is bacon?',
    choices: ['True', 'False'],
    correctAnswer: 0,
    answertext: 'The food of angels'
  }, {
    question: 'Jim didn\'t ate it?',
    choices: ['True', 'False'],
    correctAnswer: 1,
    answertext: 'Oh, He sure did.'
  }, {
    question: 'Did he deserve it?',
    choices: ['True', 'False'],
    correctAnswer: 0,
    answertext: 'NO, no he did not.'
  }, {
    question: 'He will make more?',
    choices: ['True', 'False'],
    correctAnswer: 0,
    answertext: 'He better be cooking.'
  }, {
    question: 'Will he eat it again?',
    choices: ['True', 'False'],
    correctAnswer: 1,
    answertext: 'As tempting as it sounds, No'
  }];

  var questionCounter = 0, //Tracks question number
    selections = [], //Array containing user choices
    quiz = $('.quiz-component'), //Quiz div object
    answer = $('.quiz-component'); //Quiz div object

  // Displays next requested element
  function displayNext() {
    quiz.fadeOut(function() {
      $('#question-area').remove();
      $('#answer-area').remove();

      if (questionCounter < questions.length) {

        var nextQuestion = createQuestionElement(questionCounter),
          answerQuestion = showAsnwerElement(questionCounter);

        //$('#answer-area').remove();
        quiz.append(nextQuestion).fadeIn();

        if (!(isNaN(selections[questionCounter]))) {
          $('input[value=' + selections[questionCounter] + ']').prop('checked', true);
        }

        // Controls display of 'prev' button
        if (questionCounter === 1) {
          $('#prev').show();
          //$('#question-area').remove();
          answer.append(answerQuestion).fadeIn();
        } else if (questionCounter === 0) {

          $('#prev').hide();
          $('#next').show();
        }

      } else {
        var scoreElem = displayScore();
        quiz.append(scoreElem).fadeIn();
        $('#next').hide();
        $('#prev').hide();
        $('#start').show();
      }
    });
  }

  // Display initial question
  displayNext();

  // Click handler for the 'next' button
  $('#next').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    // Suspend click listener during fade animation
    if (quiz.is(':animated')) {
      return false;
    }
    choose();

    // If no user selection, progress is stopped
    if (isNaN(selections[questionCounter])) {
      //$('.qalert').remove();
      $('.question').append('<p class=\'qalert\'>Please make a selection!<p>');
    } else {
      questionCounter++;
      displayNext();
    }
  });

  // Click handler for the 'prev' button
  $('#prev').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    if (quiz.is(':animated')) {
      return false;
    }
    choose();
    questionCounter--;
    displayNext();
  });

  // Click handler for the 'Start Over' button
  $('#start').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    if (quiz.is(':animated')) {
      return false;
    }
    questionCounter = 0;
    selections = [];
    displayNext();
    $('#start').hide();
  });

  // Animates buttons on hover
  $('.button').on('mouseenter', function() {
    $(this).addClass('active');
  });

  $('.button').on('mouseleave', function() {
    $(this).removeClass('active');
  });

  // Creates and returns the div that contains the questions and 
  // the answer selections
  function createQuestionElement(index) {
    var qElement = $('<div>', {
      id: 'question-area'
    });

    var header = $('<p class=\'question-number\'>Question ' + (index + 1) + ':</p>');
    qElement.append(header);

    var question = $('<p class=\'question\'>').append(questions[index].question);
    qElement.append(question);

    var radioButtons = createRadios(index);
    qElement.append(radioButtons);

    return qElement;
  }

  // Creates a list of the answer choices as radio inputs
  function createRadios(index) {
    var radioList = $('<ul>'),
      item,
      input = '';

    for (var i = 0; i < questions[index].choices.length; i++) {
      item = $('<li>');
      input = '<input type="radio" name="answer" value=' + i + ' />';
      input += questions[index].choices[i];
      item.append(input);
      radioList.append(item);
    }
    return radioList;
  }

  // Creates and returns the div that contains the correct anwser 
  function showAsnwerElement(index) {
    var aElement = $('<div>', {
      id: 'answer-area'
    });

    var header = $('<p class=\'correct-answers\'>').append(questions.correctAnswer).toString();
    aElement.append(header);

    var answer = $('<p class=\'answers\'>').append(questions[index].answertext);
    aElement.append(answer);

    return aElement;
  }

  // Reads the user selection and pushes the value to an array
  function choose() {
    selections[questionCounter] = +$('input[name="answer"]:checked').val();
  }



  // Computes score and returns a paragraph element to be displayed
  function displayScore() {
    var score = $('<p>', {
      id: 'question'
    });

    var numCorrect = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < selections.length; i++) {
      if (selections[i] === questions[i].correctAnswer) {
        numCorrect++;
      }
    }

    score.append('You got <span class="correntAns">' + numCorrect + '</span> questions out of <span class="correntAns">' + questions.length + '</span> right!!!');
    return score;
  }
});
```

```css
.fl-qbgi-slide {
  position: relative;
}
.img {
  visibility: hidden;
}
.fl-quiz-component {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
.title {
  background-color: $brand-primary;
}
p {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px 12px;
}
.quiz-section {
  background-color: rgba(0, 66, 131, 0.5);
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-family: $font-family-sans-serif-condensed;
  font-size: $font-size-large;
  height: auto;
  min-height: 320px;
  position: relative;
}
.quiz-component {
  height: auto;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 20px 15px 10px;
  position: relative;
  width: 85%;
}
.button {
  background-color: $gray-light;
  color: $brand-primary;
  float: right;
  margin: 0 2px 0 2px;
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-right: 5px;
  position: relative;
}
.button.active {
  background-color: $gray-light;
  color: $brand-primary;
}
button {
  float: right;
  position: relative;
}
.button a {
  color: $brand-primary;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 5px 15px;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#prev {
  display: none;
}
#start {
  display: none;
  width: 150px;
}
.correntAns {
  @extend %text-17px-bold-italics-caps;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
--- title: Quiz ---

<div class='fl-qbgi-slide'>
  <div class="img">
    <!--
                {{#if image}}
                    {{#with image}}
                        {{> image}}
                    {{/with}}
                {{else}}
                    {{#parseJSON '{
                        "srcDesktop": "/img-placeholders/botm-bg-grain-0.jpg",
                        "srcTablet": "/img-placeholders/botm-bg-grain-0.jpg",
                        "srcPhone": "/img-placeholders/botm-bg-grain-0.jpg",
                        "altText": "Beer of the Month Carousel Slide"
                    }'}}
                        {{> image}}
                    {{/parseJSON}}
                {{/if}}
  -->
  </div>

  <div class="fl-quiz-component">
    <div class="quiz-section">

      <div class="title">
        <p>Seafood Sustainability Quiz</p>
      </div>

      <div class='quiz-component'></div>

      <!-- handlebars temp area
                #quiz-questions}}
                <div class="question-block">
                    <p class="">{{{default quiz-question}}}</p>
                    <a class="">True</a>
                    <a class="">false</a>
                </div>
                /quiz-question}}
                -->

      <div class='button' id='next'><a href='#'>Next</a>
      </div>
      <div class='button' id='prev'><a href='#'>Prev</a>
      </div>
      <div class='button' id='start'> <a href='#'>Start Over</a>
      </div>
      <!-- 
                <button class='' id='next'>Next</a></button>
                <button class='' id='prev'>Prev</a></button>
                <button class='' id='start'> Start Over</a></button>
                -->

    </div>

  </div>
</div>

<script src="/js/apps/quiz-component/main.js"></script>
```

**Where do I need help**

1. Need to be able to show the correct answer of each question after the user submits the answer and before showing the next question.

I already adjusted a code to show the answer after, but is showing the next question in the same screen. Need it to show just the answer, the user will click on next and then the next question will show up.

2. Need to show a 2 different background images; one during the question and the other at the end of the quiz.

**Not require, but surely helpful**

2. If I can see this code written in Handlebars.js it would be extremely helpful, since I am trying to learn handle bars

Comment: is `answertext` a clue to your question ??

Comment: No, is part of the answer to the question, it will show after the user submits his answer whether the user answer correctly or not

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I am going to answer this in javascript(I dont know much about handlebars.js).

For showing the answer after each user submission, attach a click event to the radio buttons. I noticed you are using jquery.

```
   $("#trueRadioBut").on("click",function(){
        //check your answer
        if(right)
           display answerText;
           update score ...etc... 
        else
           wrong option code.   

   });
```

Do the same for the false Radio Button also. This should show the answerText if the user is right.

The change of background can also be done using jquery and an additional CSS class. Have a class in your css, maybe a `.endBackground` with your different background. You can then toggle it using jquery's `toggleClass()`. The `toggleClass()` toggles classes on and off  alternatively for an element.

For this you also need to make a change to your `next` button. Add a click event to it that gets the next question and redirects to the next page. When there are no more questions, toggle the background as such.

```
$(body).toggleClass("endBackground");
```

This should change your background. To change back to normal background on restarting, add a click event to your `startover` button that toggles the class off again.

Hope I have been clear. Ask me if you have any doubts.